# Quote Environment à la Strunk’s ‘The Elements of Style’

Tags: environments

How can I have a an environment similar to Strunk's *The Elements of Style*:

[image]

Comment: Please be a bit more precise about your needs. Do you want to replicate each and every stylistic aspect (including font family, and font shape and weight) of the screenshot you posted? If not, which stylistic elements are the ones you care about? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the environment, actually three:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newsavebox{\strunkbox}
\newenvironment{strunk}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\strunkbox}
   \begin{minipage}{.8\columnwidth}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}\begin{center}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{1pt}
   \leavevmode\color{red}
   \fbox{\usebox{\strunkbox}}
   \end{center}}
\newenvironment{swrong}
  {\addvspace{2ex}\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}\footnotesize}
  {\end{minipage}\ignorespacesafterend}
\newenvironment{sright}
  {\hfill\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}\footnotesize}
  {\end{minipage}\par}


\begin{document}
Words that intervene between subject and verb do not affect the number of the verb.
\begin{strunk}
\begin{swrong}
The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, 
its youth---are not soon forgotten
\end{swrong}
\begin{sright}
The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys,
its youth---is not soon forgotten
\end{sright}
\end{strunk}
A common blunder is the use of a singular verb form in a relative clause 
following ``one of\ldots'' or a similar expression when the relative is the 
subject.
\begin{strunk}
\begin{swrong}
One of the ablest scientists who has attacked this problem
\end{swrong}
\begin{sright}
One of the ablest scientists who have attacked this problem
\end{sright}

\begin{swrong}
One of those people who is never ready on time
\end{swrong}
\begin{sright}
One of those people who are never ready on time
\end{sright}
\end{strunk}
Use a singular verb form after \emph{each, either, everyone, everybody,
 neither, nobody, someone}.
\end{document}
```

Don't leave blank lines between `\end{swrong}` and `\begin{sright}`.

[image]

Comment: Why did you choose `swrong` and `sright` instead of `sleft` and `sright`?

Comment: @WChargin At the left there is the wrong usage.

Comment: @WChargin More semantic. Maybe Strunk decided to put on the right the correct construct on purpose. `;-)` Or maybe I should name the subenvironment `scorrect`. Actually I wanted to name them `wrong` and `right`, but the latter can't be used.

Comment: egreg: How can I enable hyphenation?

Comment: @blackened It *is* enabled.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad.

Comment: egreg: How can I enforce \noindent for the paragraph following your environment?

Comment: @blackened I see no indent in my examples.

Comment: It is not your examples. But if my setup includes paragraph indents (say, in a book class), it also indents following your environment. Is there a way to enforce it to not indent? (Except, of course, doing it manually each time.)

Comment: @blackened Sorry, but my example doesn't do anything special about indentation and, indeed, the top line *is* indented. Just don't leave a blank line after `\end{strunk}` if you don't want the subsequent paragraph indented. If this doesn't work, then there's something else in your document and a new question with a MWE is needed.

Comment: Now I see it. I am working in LyX. I assume the problem is related with how it handles TeX code. (Just checked the source and realized that LyX inserts a blank line by itself.)

Comment: @blackened Another reason for suggesting my friends not to use LyX, thanks. `;-)`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than as an environment, I create `\strunk{}{}` for the task.  It will not break across page breaks.  I have limited `\textwidth` here, instead of using columns.  The `\strunk` macro will occupy 85% of `\textwidth`, plus the red border.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\parskip 1ex
\textwidth 3in
\parindent 0in
\fboxrule 3pt
\newcommand\strunk[2]{%
\par{\centering
\color{red}{\fbox{\color{black}\scriptsize
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\parskip 1em
\raggedright#1
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.05\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\parskip 1em
\raggedright#2
\end{minipage}
}}
\par}
}
\begin{document}
Words that intervene between subject and verb do not affect the number of the verb.
\strunk
{The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---are not soon 
forgotten}
{The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---is not soon 
forgotten}
A common blunder is the use of a singular verb form in a relative clause 
following ``one of\ldots'' or a similar expression when the relative is the 
subject.
\strunk
{One of the ablest scientists who has attacked this problem

One of those people who is never ready on time}
{One of the ablest scientists who have attacked this problem

One of those people who are never ready on time}
Use a singular verb form after \textit{each, either, everyone, everybody,
 neither, nobody, someone}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Steven. In my question I forgot to mention that the red border was just for emphasis. I am working in LyX, and the first part of your example (first box) works fine when I insert your code  as “Tex Code”, but the second one does not work. (I am guessing that a problem with inserting Tex code in LyX.)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for those (like me) who doesn't manage *low level* commands like egreg and Steven. It uses [`tcolorbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) and its possibility of arranging two texts side by side. `strunk` is an environment instead of a `command` but I hope it doesn't matter.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newtcolorbox{strunk}{notitle, colback=white, colframe=red, width=.9\linewidth,
              arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, 
              sidebyside, lower separated=false, sidebyside align=top, sidebyside gap=4mm,
              before={\par\smallskip\pagebreak[0]\parindent=0pt\centering},
              after={\par\smallskip},
              fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
              boxsep=0mm,
              left=2mm, right=2mm, top=2mm, bottom=2mm,
              }

\begin{document}
Words that intervene between subject and verb do not affect the number of the verb.
%
\begin{strunk}
{The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---are not soon 
forgotten}\tcblower
{The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---is not soon 
forgotten}
\end{strunk}

A common blunder is the use of a singular verb form in a relative clause 
following ``one of\ldots'' or a similar expression when the relative is the 
subject.


\begin{strunk}
{One of the ablest scientists who has attacked this problem\\

One of those people who is never ready on time}\tcblower
{One of the ablest scientists who have attacked this problem\\

One of those people who are never ready on time}
 \end{strunk}

  Use a singular verb form after \textit{each, either, everyone, everybody,
 neither, nobody, someone}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `tcolorbox` it's a pain not indenting what comes after it.

Comment: Ups! you're right. I didn't notice the indentation. But I neither don't know how to do it.

Comment: @egreg: `parskip` packages does it, but it also suppresses first paragraph indentation.

Comment: Just use `after=` instead of `after=\par\smallskip` if there should be no new paragraph (i.e. no indention) after `tcolorbox` ...

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm But without `after=\par`, initial `centering` doesn't work and `begin{center}...\end{center}` introduces undesired vertical space before and after the box.

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm `after=` works when `tcolorbox` width is `\textwidth`, but not when it is shorter like in this case.

Comment: @Ignasi Sorry, I was too fast with my first comment. Since the accepted answer also uses `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, I would say the vertical space is OK for the OP. I posted a variant as an answer since the comment space is too short. Another possibility would be to stretch the bounding box to fill the `\textwidth` and then use `after=` (but I have'nt used this in my posting).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `tcolorbox` alternative in two variants.

The first one builds upon the answer of @Ignasi. I polished it at some spots, especially to answer the indention questions which came up in the comments:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newtcolorbox{strunk}{colback=white,colframe=red,
  width=.9\linewidth,
  size=fbox,boxrule=2pt,
  sharp corners,lower separated=false,
  sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
  sidebyside gap=4mm,
  before={\begin{center}},
  after={\end{center}},
  fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
}

\begin{document}
Words that intervene between subject and verb do not affect the number of the verb.
%
\begin{strunk}
  The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---are not soon
  forgotten.
\tcblower
  The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---is not soon
  forgotten.
\end{strunk}
A common blunder is the use of a singular verb form in a relative clause
following ``one of\ldots'' or a similar expression when the relative is the
subject.
\begin{strunk}
  One of the ablest scientists who has attacked this problem\bigskip

  One of those people who is never ready on time
\tcblower
  One of the ablest scientists who have attacked this problem\bigskip

  One of those people who are never ready on time
\end{strunk}
Use a singular verb form after \textit{each, either, everyone, everybody,
neither, nobody, someone}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the OP mentioned that the red borders are not really intended to appear in the document, here is a second variant without borders:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\newtcolorbox{strunk}{blanker,
  width=.9\linewidth,
  sharp corners,lower separated=false,
  sidebyside,sidebyside align=top,
  sidebyside gap=4mm,
  before={\begin{center}},
  after={\end{center}},
  fontupper=\small, fontlower=\small,
}

\begin{document}
Words that intervene between subject and verb do not affect the number of the verb.
%
\begin{strunk}
  The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---are not soon
  forgotten.
\tcblower
  The bittersweet flavor of youth---its trials, its joys, its youth---is not soon
  forgotten.
\end{strunk}
A common blunder is the use of a singular verb form in a relative clause
following ``one of\ldots'' or a similar expression when the relative is the
subject.
\begin{strunk}
  One of the ablest scientists who has attacked this problem
\tcblower
  One of the ablest scientists who have attacked this problem
\end{strunk}
\begin{strunk}
  One of those people who is never ready on time
\tcblower
  One of those people who are never ready on time
\end{strunk}
Use a singular verb form after \textit{each, either, everyone, everybody,
neither, nobody, someone}.

\end{document}
```

[image]